# Apache permissions to allow both user and web server to edit /var/www

Tags: permissions, apache2, root

For security reasons I would like to disable root access via ssh.

I created a new user (user1) with administrative permissions.

```
adduser user1
usermod -aG sudo user1
```

and assigned the /www directory to this user.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

(My folders structure is www/site1.com, www/site2.com, etc.)

My sites need to write some files (such as sitemaps, rss feeds, etc.) so I set the permissions of the www directory to:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Now, however, user user1 works perfectly via shell with the sudo command, but can no longer add/edit/delete files and folders in the /www directory and its subdirectories via sftp.

I read many guides, how to set up apache permissions to increase security, to share administration with other users, etc. etc. etc.

But I still did not understand how to solve my problem.

Currently to be able to handle files on my server via sftp I have to use the root user, with peace of mind for security.

Did I miss something about setting user or folders permissions?

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to set different *group* and *user* access for files and directories, and this will allow both Apache and your user1 user to edit what's in `/var/www` without requiring root/sudo and without making anything world-writable.

So, set the "user" permission inside `/var/www` to `user1`.  Set the "group" permission to `www-data` (but ONLY for the specific files or directories that the web server needs to write to).

```
sudo chown -R user1:user1 /var/www
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/specific-file
```

You should avoid letting the web server write to the entire `/var/www` directory and its contents, instead giving the above group permission only to the specific files where this is necessary.  It is a good security principle to limit the web server's access to write to files to only those files that it is strictly necessary for - and it is a good idea to try and ensure those files are not executed directly (aren't .php or other executable scripts, for example).

Comment: My problem is that I don't know what are the files that are added or modified by the server. For example, I have sites with thousands of pages, and a script that generates the sitemap_index.xml and sitemap.xml files. Every 5000 URL is created a new file (eg. sitemap_15000.xml) to which later is rewritten to add all new URLs, and fails to write these files if it is not www-data, but I can not touch the files in sftp with the user user1 if is www-data.

Comment: @alebal You can create a directory called `sitemaps` and make it writable by `www-data` and put your sitemaps in that directory. This way you won't have to worry about permissions being modified on that directory as users would very rarely (if ever) need to touch that directory since it is populated by apache only.

Comment: I thought about it too, it's not a bad idea, but I have about 50 sites on this server each with its sitemaps, it would be a great job to change all the sitemap scripts, files, internal and external links, etc. Moreover the permissions on the sitemap files are modified and set by the php file that creates them, they should be able to do it themselves, no?

Comment: Let's say the server needs to write to a folder owned by `user1:www-data` , is it safe to [set the permissions on that folder to `0775`](https://superuser.com/a/646070) intead of `0755`? Or should I instead allow everything to `www-data` and just SSH with that user like suggested below?

Comment: Yes setting the group write bit is fine, though you'll need a way of ensuring new files created in there get the permissions you want. No, do not ever use www-data to log in as, or add any user to the www-data group, or give www-data any additional permissions beyond necessary. It's an *unprivileged* account. Some other answers are recommending bad security practices

Answer (score 0):

If you change the directory with a setgid bit, these problems should be history.

Try this

```
chmod 2775 /var/www
```

With the setgid bit set, all files in this directory belong to the group www-data (this should be the standard user and group of the folder, www-data:www-data) and not a user.

So as long as user1 is in the group www-data, the user should be able to modify, delete and open files.

Give it a try.

First enter the user to the appropriate group. Simplest way

```
sudo nano /etc/group
```

Find www-data and enter user1 after the ":" at the end

LOGOUT/LOGIN again

Now create the folder e.g.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www2
```

and then put the setgid bit on it

```
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www2 && sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www2
```

now enter the folder, create another folder or file.
It should work and look something like this (please make sure you see the "s" when using ls)

See here e.g.

```
simmel@tron:/var/www2
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwsr-x 1 www-data www-data   8 Feb 21 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     126 Feb 21 10:26 ..
drwxrwsr-x 1 simmel   www-data   0 Feb 21 10:28 blah
```

As you can see for the group part there is a RWS shown instead of RWX shown.

Comment: When I try to create a directory it says: permission denied.

but I'm not sure about the group of user1... when I created it I also gave: usermod -aG sudo user1

Is User1 in the www-data group? How can I understand it and in case assign it?

Comment: I added the info for you

Comment: I tried, but something doesn't seem to work yet.

I added user1 in the file etc/group, also made a reboot of the server. I have set the permissions on /var/www, because I have there all my sites, I can not change folder.

But it still does not work, if I connect in sftp with FileZilla and user1, I do not have permission to create files and folders.

In the end I still can not disable the root user, because I need to manage the files of my sites.

Comment: well there might be another way, it is ugly but should def. work. edit /etc/passwd and give the user www-data a /bin/bash and also a password and login as www-data, this way you have no problems at all. but you might think a moment about security. maybe a sftp server could help here, vsftp is more or less easy to setup with virtual users (which then can point towrds user www-data).

Comment: Umh... I do it to increase security, I don't want to risk decreasing it even more.

I think rather calmly and with time to change the structure of files in my Sites, creating folders for sitemap files and images to be assigned to the user www-data, everything else to user1, but it will take some time unfortunately...

Comment: you should consider using sftp through ssh with keys, this way you could even use the user www-data for it. If you work on windows take a look at winscp and putty. create a passwordless ssh key and put it on your server.

Comment: What you mean? I use Ubuntu (Linux Mint) also for desktop PCs and I use the key to access sftp, I'm missing something?

Comment: well if you use sftp over ssh with keys, you could also use the www-data user. Just give the user www-data a /bin/bash in /etc/passwd and a /var/www/.ssh dir with the authorized_keys file in it and you are good to go.